# iOS presenting a viewcontroller 's view to the top anywhere

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I have 3 normal views and each one is controlled by a viewcontroller,

```
    view1---->View1controller (rootviewcontroller)
       view2---->View2controller
      view3---->View3controller
```

Then I have a special module

```
             View4--->View4controller
```

What happened is there's background thread exists in rootviewcontroller. 
I could anythwere among view1, view2, or view3.    When certain condition arised, the background thread will fire up the View4 by

```
     [presentviewcontroller:View4controller]
```

I would like View4 to rise to top and doesn't matter if I am in view2, View3. But the issue is the code to present is in View1controller.  So If I am in view2 and the special codnition is met there would be UIAlertView popped up from the View1controller's background thread stating to user the special condition arised.

So How do I present View4 to the TOP from View1controller when I am in View2?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can't do it that way. You either have to pass view4 to View2 and let it present it, maybe using something like this:

```
@property UIViewController *currentView;
@synthesize currentView;
//and when trying to push view4 do the following
if (currentView!=nil) {

[currentView presentViewContoller:View4Cont];

}
```

or use view1 to dismiss View2 and present View4 at the same time (using the animated property = NO).

Also make sure that you do all interface specific operations from the main thread.

Comment: I have no idea if I am at View1, View2, View3 at any moment. so how do I know what's my currentview?

Comment: well that's the point behind having a uiviewcontroller instance variable called currentView, whenever you present a view controller, you should set that variable to the presented controller.